# Seaborn despine with two y-scales (twinx)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

How can I keep `seaborn.despine` from putting both of my y-scales onto the left side of my plot?
The best I've come up with so far is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

sns.set_style("white")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(np.random.rand(10))
ax2 =ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(100*np.random.rand(10))
sns.despine(ax=ax, right=True, left=True)
sns.despine(ax=ax2, left=True, right=False)
```

But any other combination will either not despine the y-axes or put the right axis onto the left.

Output of the above: (desired output has no spines, just numbers on left and right)

[image]

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly, cause if I run your snippet I get one y-scale on one side and one y-scale on the other side. Is that not want you want?

Comment: maybe you can add a figure..

Comment: Fair point - I didn't set the seaborn style in my question, which makes despining unnecessary!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess that's what you want then.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

sns.set_style("white")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(np.random.rand(10))
ax2 =ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(100*np.random.rand(10))
sns.despine(ax=ax, right=True, left=True)
sns.despine(ax=ax2, left=True, right=False)
ax2.spines['right'].set_color('white')
```

[image: no spines, just numbers on left and right]

Comment: If you want to show the axis line on both sides (which is what I wanted to do), then you do it like this:
```
sns.despine(ax=ax, right=True, left=False)
sns.despine(ax=ax2, left=True, right=False)
```